# Impedir insertar o hacer update cuando haya ya un registro en el mismo grupo (triggers)

Tags: sql, plsql

Quiero hacer que no se pueda insertar ni hacer update cuando haya ya un `coordinador` en el mismo `departamento` en una tabla `empleados`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER UnCoordinador
 AFTER UPDATe
 ON EMPLEADOS
  DECLARE
    BEGIN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(EMP_NO) FROM EMPLEADOS 
            WHERE TIPO='COORDINADOR')<1 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        raiserror('registro NO agregado', 10, 1) 
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

Comment: Buenos días. Cuál es el error que se te presenta ? Creo que te esta faltando la parte de "En el mismo departamento" que seguramente es un join con departamentos.

Comment: Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :D

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay varios puntos que afectan tu propósito:
- El trigger que usas se lanza después de que se a actualizado la tabla, no afecta al insert
- Para que se lance antes debes usar instead of

```
CREATE TRIGGER UnCoordinador
  ON EMPLEADOS
  instead of insert
as  
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(EMP_NO) FROM EMPLEADOS 
        WHERE TIPO='COORDINADOR')=0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (columas....) (select columnas.. from inserted)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        raiserror('registro NO agregado', 10, 1) 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

**Corrección* creo que usas DB Oracle, ahí existe before para usar en lugar de instead of update**

Comment: Este es el error que me da :

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar el momento en el que el Trigger se va a ejecutar. En el código usas el trigger `AFTER` (después) cuando debería ser `BEFORE` (antes).

Y si necesitas que sea antes del update y el insert también debes especificarlo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER UnCoordinador
 BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
 ON EMPLEADOS
  DECLARE
    BEGIN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(EMP_NO) FROM EMPLEADOS 
            WHERE TIPO='COORDINADOR')<1 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        raiserror('registro NO agregado', 10, 1) 
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```